# How to send back data automatically from a server back to the client and display it?

Tags: php, redirect

So I have this "client" PHP page, and a "server" PHP page. And I'm trying to send a value from the client to the server using the GET-method. And then I want to send the information back again from the server to the client and display it. How do I accomplish this?

At first the client page contains merely a link to the server page that also sends some information with it. E.g: `<a href="server.php?firstname=myfirstname&lastname=nylastname">link</a>`

But when the server has sent back the data, I do not want to display the link anymore. I just want to show the information, something like:

first name: myfirstname
last name: mylastname

How do I accomplish this? After doing some research I found this redirect function, but I'm not sure if I can or if I should use it:

```
function redirect($url, $statusCode = 303){
            header('Location: ' . $url, true, $statusCode);
            die();
        }
```

And if I should use it: How do I send the data that I need back to the client with it using GET? Can I just do something like:

```
<?php
    $firstname = $_GET["firstname"];
    $lastname = $_GET["lastname"];

    redirect("client.php?firstname=$firstname&lastname=$lastname") //I'm guessing putting the variables in like this doesn't work...

    function redirect($url, $statusCode = 303){
        header('Location: ' . $url, true, $statusCode);
        die();
    }
?>
```

But even if this works. I still don't know how to change the appearance of the client page when I send back the data from the server page. Is it even possible?

Oh: And I want to send the information back to the client as the MIME type `text/plain`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, create a index.php and put this in it.

```
<?php

$firstname = $_GET['firstname'];
$lastname = $_GET['lastname'];

if ($firstname || $lastname){
    $print = true;
} else {
    $print = false;
}

?>

<html>
<body>

<?php
if($print==true){
    echo "Firstname: ".$firstaname."<br>Lastname: ".$lastname;
}
?>
<a href="page2.php?firstname=myfirstname&lastname=nylastname">link</a>
```

Then make a page2.php and put this in it.

```
<?php

$firstname = $_GET['firstname'];
$lastname = $_GET['lastname'];

header("location: index.php?firstname=$firstname&lastname=$lastname");
```

Comment: Yeah well even if that may work technically, I'm not sure if I'm allowed to use it. The reason I have these maybe weird demands is that I'm doing an assignment on a distance course at the university. And it says that I should "do a HTML document with a link that points to a web server program", and that this "web server program" should "receive the data sent with the GET method, and send it back to the web client.

As far as I understand those requirements. The different "programs" are just different documents. So I don't think I can use just one document for this. I might be wrong though.